# Изначальная позиция элемента C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

В форме имеется `label1` (движущаяся надпись), которую пользователь может двигать на 5px вниз при наведении курсра. Требуется добавить кнопку, которая при событии `onclick` возращала бы `label1` (движущаяся надпись) на ИСХОДНУЮ позицию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопку добавил, но не совсем понимаю, что нужно прописать в событии `onlick` (чтобы `label1` приняла исходную позицию). Пробовал с помощью `align`, ничего не выходит.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Label1->Left=Label1->Left-5;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Label1->Left=Label1->Left+5;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Label1->Top=Label1->Top+5;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button4Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Label1->Top=Label1->Top+-5;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::RadioButton1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Label1->Font->Color=clWindowText;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::RadioButton2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Label1->Font->Color=clBlue;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::RadioButton3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Label1->Font->Color=clRed;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button5Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Label1->Caption=Edit1->Text;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Label1MouseMove(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int X,
          int Y)
{
    if(CheckBox1->Checked==true) {
        Label1->Top=Label1->Top+5;
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите код в текстовом виде, а не картинкой

Comment: Добавил код выше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы вернуть на исходную позицию, нужно ее знать. Попробуем самый простой вариант. Вначале нам нужно место, где эта позиция будет хранится. Не будет сильно хитрить, и возле `TForm1 *Form1;` добавим ещё пару строк

```
TForm1 *Form1;
int origin_top;
int origin_left;
```

потом в конструкторе инициализируем их

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
  origin_top = Label1->Top;
  origin_left = Label1->Left;
}
```

Теперь, можно написать код, который восстановит начальную позицию:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ButtonXXXClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    Label1->Top = origin_top ;
    Label1->Left = origin_left;
}
```

Аналогичным образом можно "восстанавливать" и другие свойства.

Конечно, хорошо бы эти запомненные координаты сделать приватными переменными класса TForm1. Но это уже  на домашнее задание.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: @ВладиславБирюков поставьте галку слева от ответа, если вопрос решён